# multiplication by invertible matrix preserves open-ness?

Tags: matrices

How do I show that, if $U$ is an open subset of some $\mathbb{R^{m\cdot n}}$ then $Ug$ where $g$ is an invertible matrix is also open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** If $g$ is an invertible matrix, then the map $x \mapsto gx$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I find it hard to really pin down what the "continuity" for the map between matrices means. I'm not sure how the left multiplication by $g$ would affect to the topology of $gx$. It seems very exotic and complicated without having any relevant theorems about the topology of matrix. Could you give me some insight?